# signalR use/persistance after a POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Currently having a look at the use of signalR to present users with a progress report of a file while it is processing. I'm using asp.net MVC 4. When doing a post/get via Ajax I have no trouble getting the status changes.

Since I need to upload a file (without ajax, since 1: I cannot require users to have js enabled in order to submit the file; 2: I don't believe it's readily available to do such a task, apart from maybe HTML5).

**EDIT:**
When I say I cannot require users to have JS, I mean submitting the file cannot rely on JS because that is a core functionality. However, I would like those who have JS enabled to see the progress of the processing/import into another program. I am not currently interested/caring about the actual file transfer progress, but more so sending status messages back to the current state of an import into the program.

What approach would be suggested in order to achieve the goal of updating progress as the file processes after I have called the form Post?
Note:

Example Code:

```
$(function () {
    var fileUploadHub = $.connection.fileUploadHub;

    fileUploadHub.updateProgress = function (value) {
        updateProgressBar(value);
    };

    fileUploadHub.updateStatusText = function (text) {
        alert("you got to updateStatus");
        updateText(text);
    };
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.start();
});

function updateProgressBar(value) {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: value });
}

function updateText(text) {
    $("#statusText").append("<li>" + text + "</li>");
}
```

//Form : Backed by a Model

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( "UploadFile", "FileUpload", FormMethod.Post,
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <input type="file" id="Files" name="Files" accept="text/xml" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SubmitFile(MyModel model)
{
  ...
  ProcessFile(model.file)
  ...
}

public void ProcessFile(File file)
{
  var myHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<FileUploadHub>();
  myHub.Clients.updateStatusText("testz");
}
```

Hub Class:

```
public class FileUploadHub : Hub
{
}
```

Comment: `I cannot require users to have js enabled in order to submit the file;` - if you can't rely on the fact that users have javascript enabled you could simply forget about SignalR. Not only that its client requires javascript but it has a dependency on jQuery. Now let's see about your second requirement: it's true that currently you cannot rely on browsers supporting the HTML5 File API, so you could use some existing file upload components that have many functionality one of which is progress reporting. So do you really need SignalR for that?

Comment: You say you can't do AJAX because you can't require JS? SignalR also requires JS, so I don't think you're going to have much success with it then either.

Comment: I should clarify a bit. I cannot make a dependency of functionality (uploading the file) based on js, but a nicety (those who have JS) would be able to see progress of the file upload. The file submit will take place regardless of js/ajax, but progress messages will depend entirely on JS being enabled of course. I will update question to make this more clear.

Comment: @LukeG Gotcha, thanks for clarifying. Lemme see if I can answer the question now.

Comment: @Darin - The functionality I'm mainly looking for is giving notifications on processing/manipulating the file. For example I have some sort of file (maybe xml for this example) in which I want to do any sort of processing and importing into another program. I'm not necessarily caring about the progress of the file upload atm, as assumption is the file will be rather small.

Comment: i am not mvc guy but still like to know when u submit ur form then how SubmitFile() this action will call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you would need to do is also send back the user's SignalR ConnectionId with the POST. Then, when the post starts you would need to get the HubContext and throughout the logic of the POST you can send notifications back to the specific client via that ConnectionId.

1. Add an input type="hidden" to your form.

   ```
   <input type="hidden" id="mySignalRConnectionIdHidden" name="SignalRConnectionId" />
   ```
2. Assuming JavaScript enabled and you connect to the hub, set the value of the hidden input to the value of the connectionid from SignalR in the start() callback.

   ```
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function ()
   {
       $("#mySignalRConnectionIdHidden").val($.connection.connectionId);
   });
   ```
3. First step of the POST to the server side grab the HubContext for your Hub and get the client that you're going to talk back to.

   ```
   // Get the value of the hidden from the request
   string currentClientConnectionId = Request.Form["SignalRConnectionId"];

   // Get the hub context
   IHubContext myHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

   // Resolve a the client that corresponds to the current request
   dynamic currentClient = myHubContext.Client(currentClientConnectionId);
   ```
4. At various points throughout your POST handling logic you can now send back messages to the client that initiated the upload:

   ```
   ... do some stuff ...

   currentClient.stepOneCompleted();

   .... do some more stuff ...

   currentClient.stepTwoCompleted();

   ... etc ...
   ```

Obviously in step 4 you could also pass data back to the client as parameters, I'm just not showing that here.

Finally, for clients that don't have JS enabled or fail to connect for some reason, you can detect that the form value is empty on the POST and then you know there was no SignalR connection made. Then you can just set currentClient = null and detect that throughout the places where you would invoke the client callbacks and skip the callbacks altogether.

Comment: Does this approach work for you in a typical POST of a webform (eg. using an <input type="submit"/> element)? SignalR seems to get the IHubContext of the specified Client just fine, but there is no update to the page when I try to use the callbacks. NOTE: I can get page updates via callback when doing a POST via Ajax. Is the issue I'm encountering just a limitation since the POST call isn't done via Ajax?

Comment: No, if you're POSTing the page itself back you're going to lose all state. You would have to POST the form back to a target iFrame or one of those kinds of tricks.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that was probably the case. Sorry for some of the basic questions/misconceptions, just pretty new to Web work in general. Thank's so much for your help!